# Perform Inner Join on a subquery that has more than one column, in HQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to join a table with the result of a sub-query (Sub-query returns the result with 3 columns) in HQL but I'm getting a syntax error `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token`.

It looks like `INNER JOIN` doesn't work in HQL like it does in SQL, so I looked at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries but it didn't help.

**HQL Query**

```
SELECT R
FROM Table R
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT T.id.col1, T.id.col2, MAX(T.col3) max_num
   FROM Table T
   GROUP BY T.id.col1
) b ON R.id.col1 = b.id.col1 AND R.col3 = b.max_num
WHERE R.id.col3 = :param
GROUP BY R.id.col1
ORDER BY R.col3 DESC
```

**Actual Result**

`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 81`

**Expected Result**

Unique Rows that contain the max value of T.col3.

*Note: SQL version of the above query works fine.*

Answer (score 1):

you have not used any aggregate function so no need group by

```
SELECT R.*
    FROM Table R
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT T.id.col1, T.id.col2, MAX(T.col3) max_num
       FROM Table T
       GROUP BY T.id.col1,T.id.col2
    ) b ON R.id.col1 = b.id.col1 AND R.col3 = b.max_num
    WHERE R.id.col3 = :param

    ORDER BY R.col3 DESC
```

Comment: On the right track, but this isn't valid HQL syntax AFAIK.  Also, you have changed the aggregation subquery in a way which changes the meaning from what the OP has.  I think the current version is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I would write your HQL query as this:

```
from R as r
where r.id.col3 = :param and r.col3 = (select max(t.col3) from Table t where t.r = r)
```

This assumes that the `T` entity has a reference to the `R` entity called `r`.  If not, then change the above code accordingly.

Comment: In the question above, there is only 1 entity, R and T are aliases of `Table` (dummy table name)